# How do I get a backgroundworker to report more than just an int?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I want the backgroundworker to send back some custom information to the ProgressChanged event handler, but it seems that all it can send is an int.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: That int isn't supposed to be used to send back data. It's used to send back the error code. That's my understanding, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReportProgress has an overloaded method which takes in a UserState object which can be any object. You can pass anything that inherits the object class in and then parse it on your ProgressChanged event handler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprogressbar.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use the `UserState` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I was successful with is by building my own Background Worker class with some extra properties.  During the background worker "DOWORK" handler, as I'm doing things, I set other properties on the object... int, string, other objects, etc..  Then, issue the ReportProgress with whatever percentage I'm dealing with...

Since the background worker is passed to whatever is listening for the feedback, you can then read the values of Properties on the background worker via "get/set"